# Application hangs if training tff Model using a created Client DataSet

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-federated

I create a `DataSet` following EMNIST. But When I train my model it seems to be trapped in a infinite loop and RAM gets filled in a short time. Here is the code. I print my dataset and EMNIST dataset to draw a comparison (`BAL1` is my DataSet):

```py
print(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
  collections.OrderedDict(
    (name, ds.value) for name, ds 
    in sorted(f["examples"][BAL1.client_ids[0]].items())
  )))
example_dataset = emnist_train.create_tf_dataset_for_client(
  emnist_train.client_ids[0])
print(example_dataset)
```

Here is the result:

```
    <TensorSliceDataset shapes: OrderedDict([(label, ()), (pixels, (28, 28))]), types: OrderedDict([(label, tf.int32), (pixels, tf.float32)])>
    <TensorSliceDataset shapes: OrderedDict([(label, ()), (pixels, (28, 28))]), types: OrderedDict([(label, tf.int32), (pixels, tf.float32)])>
```

and this is the part I use `BAL1` to replace EMNIST:

```py
sample_clients = BAL1.client_ids[0:NUM_CLIENTS]
 
federated_train_data = make_federated_data(BAL1, sample_clients)
    
state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
print('round 1, metrics={}'.format(metrics))
```

My model can work well with EMNIST. But if I change EMNIST to my dataset, the "Python3 Google compute Engine" becomes busy. Even after waiting a long time nothing is calculated, so I have to interrupt it.

Comment: Could you try preprocessing the client data with a take function? That is, purely for testing, apply something like `BAL1 = BAL1.preprocess(lambda x: x.take(10))`? TFF should be dataset agnostic, so I am wondering if there are simply many more elements in these client datasets? Keep in mind TFF will block on the slowest client, so your round runtime will be determined by the client with the *largest* amount of data, rather than something like the average.

Comment: Than you for your advice. Your are right that there are many elements in client datasets. I wait a long time and I find there are more than hundred thousand elements in 5 clients. I have a error in my logic.